# CGI- Getting the mean of 10 inputs given by user thru HTML

Tags: html, c, cgi

For our homework, we had to create an HTML that gets 10 inputs from user using forms. Then, from those 10 inputs, we had to create a program that gets the mean of the 10 inputs and then display the results. This is what I've done so far: 
*We had to store those 10 inputs in an array first*

CGI code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
char *data;
int i;
int nums[10];
double sum = 0.0;
double size=0.0;
printf("Content-type:text/html");
printf("<html><body>");

data=getenv("QUERY_STRING");
if(data)
    {
        for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
        sscanf(data,"nums[i]=%d", &nums[i]);
        sum += nums[i];
        }
    size=sum/10;
    printf("The average is %d\n",size);
    }
return 0;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action='/cgi-bin/trust.cgi'>
        <a: input type=text value='' name=a />
        <b: input type=text value='' name=b />
        <c: input type=text value='' name=c />
        <d: input type=text value='' name=d />
        <e: input type=text value='' name=e />
        <f: input type=text value='' name=f />
        <g: input type=text value='' name=g />
        <h: input type=text value='' name=h />
        <i: input type=text value='' name=i />
        <j: input type=text value='' name=j />
        <input type=submit value='Compute'>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

QUESTION: I keep getting "Error 500: Server error! Premature end of script headers: trust.cgi". This is my first time coding this type of code and I would appreciate any help.

EDIT: taken care of that Error 500. But now my problem is that it's giving me the wrong answers for the average that I need? Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Does the `data` string actually contain `nums[i]=`, or is it more like `nums[0]=`? Right now your `sscanf()` is looking for the former. Also, you need to increment where you are search for values in the string; currently you are starting from the beginning every time.

Comment: chrisaycock isn't the i++ in the for for that part? i'm so sorry i'm confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is not really HTML, so [tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/) it up first.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Get The Average</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action='/cgi-bin/trust.cgi'>
      <input type="text" value='' name="a"></br>
      <input type="text" value='' name="b"></br>
      <input type="text" value='' name="c"></br>
      <input type="text" value='' name="d"></br>
      <input type="text" value='' name="e"></br>
      <input type="text" value='' name="f"></br>
      <input type="text" value='' name="g"></br>
      <input type="text" value='' name="h"></br>
      <input type="text" value='' name="i"></br>
      <input type="text" value='' name="j"></br>
      <input type="submit" value='Compute'>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Parsing the query string with `sscanf()` is probably not the best idea and your Prof. seems to hold the same opinion, as you wrote. Nevertheless *with* `scanf()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  char *data;
  int i;
  int nums[10] = {0};
  double sum = 0.0;
  double size = 0.0;
  printf("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n");
  printf("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Here's The Average</title></head><body>");
  // TODO: check if data is not NULL
  data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
  printf("%s</br>\n", data);
  if (data) {
      // That's an abomination. Obviously.
      sscanf(data, "a=%d&b=%d&c=%d&d=%d&e=%d&f=%d&g=%d&h=%d&i=%d&j=%d",
             &nums[0], &nums[1], &nums[2], &nums[3], &nums[4], &nums[5],
             &nums[6], &nums[7], &nums[8], &nums[9]);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      sum += nums[i];
    }
    size = sum / 10;
    printf("The average is %f\n", size);
  }
  printf("</body></html>");
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It looks indeed a wee bit better with `strtok`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char *data;
  char *token;
  int i = 0;
  int nums[10] = { 0 };
  double sum = 0.0;
  double size = 0.0;
  printf("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n");
  printf
      ("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Here's The Average with strtok</title></head><body>");
  // TODO: check if data != NULL
  data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
  printf("%s</br>\n", data);
  if (data) {
    token = strtok(data, "&");
    while (token) {
      // look for the '='
      while (*token != '=') {
        token++;
      }
      // and skip it
      token++;
      nums[i++] = atoi(token);
      // check if we have enough
      // the constant "10" should better be #define'd
      if (i == 10) {
        break;
      }
      token = strtok(NULL, "&");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      sum += nums[i];
    }
    size = sum / 10;
    printf("The average is %f\n", size);
  }
  printf("</body></html>");
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Tokenizing the string alone is not enough, you have to convert/unescape the HTTP escaped characters (the hexadecimal values starting with `%`), too, if you expect them.

Answer (score 0):

The `500` error is caused by an incorrect HTTP header. According to [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html), the headers of an HTTP response should be separated from the response body by two CRLF line breaks (i.e., `"\r\n\r\n"`). You can fix this by changing the first `printf()` statement to:

```
printf("Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n");
```

> (**Edit:** [The CGI specification is not as strict](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-6.2) — all you need is a blank line between the headers and body, so presumably `"\n\n"` will also work.)

Also, your parsing code is completely wrong. Your match string of `nums[i]=` passed to `sscanf()` will only match `numsi=`, which appears nowhere in the query string. Also you are passing the same input string (`data`) to `sscanf()` every time. Try using [`strsep()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html) instead.

Finally, you are trying to print the result (`double size;`) as an integer (`"%d"`). You should use a format specifier of `"%f"` instead.

Comment: I see that a single `\n` is required, but I don't think `\r` or a second newline makes sense. CR/LF linebreaks are a typical DOS/Windows legacy.

Comment: @Olaf Two CRLF linebreaks are used to mark the end of the HTTP headers and the start of the HTTP body, as per [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html).

Comment: Hmm, I could have bet on Unix-style linebreaks. Aynway, thanks for correcting me and providing an authoritative reference. Would be a good idea to have that in your answer.

Comment: Will fscanf help me store the inputs that I have received into an array successfully?

Comment: @KyleSanchez Not really. You would probably be better off using `strsep()` (or `strtok()`) to split the query string into individual pieces before calling `sscanf()`.

Comment: Oh, okay. That was what actually our professor suggested! Okay, thank you so much!

Comment: Just for the record, RFC2616 defines HTTP. The relevant standards document here ought to be [RFC 3875](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875), the Common Gateway Interface.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Good point. It turns out that the CGI specification is less strict, and only "a blank line" is needed as a separator. (So presumably `\n\n` would also be fine.)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage will I use another char pointer for the strtok thing? Or will I use the char *data I have originally used above? Thanks

Comment: @KyleSanchez The `man` page for `getenv()` doesn't say you *can't* overwrite the return values, but to be on the safe side, I would recommend using `strdup()` (if available) or `malloc()` and `strcpy()` (otherwise) to create a copy of the query string for passing to `strsep() / strtok()`.